# Details grid view refreshes the whole page unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view and details view. My details view is in the update panel and it should be displayed for edits of the gridview. I have a file Upload control inside detailsview, Now when I click the upload button the whole page gets refreshed.

What do I do and where do I do? I think it should be some problem with the postback triggers.

Comment: well its problem of file uploader you can not work with file uploader inside updatepanel.. this is problem.. howerver you can use postback trigger to submit file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , you must post back when uploading a file, but try to do the following:

in the file uploader event : call the following method:

```
updatepanelName.Update();
```

Answer (score 4):

use this..

http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2008/04/01/file-upload-in-updatepanel-asp.net-ajax.aspx

Comment: I tried this ., but my button is in the detailsview.,so it says it cant find that control ., I have <updatepanel><contentTemplate><detailsview><button>........?????

Answer (score 3):

set

```
 <Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="your fileupload control id" />                                       
                                            </Triggers>
```

in update panel

Comment: Yes I did that but I get an error A control with ID 'ImageUploader' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'DetailsViewUpdatePanel'.

Comment: But I have <editItemTemplate> <asp:fileUploadcontrol id="ImageUploader" runat="server">

Answer (score 1):

If, it should not get refreshed then use the `AutoPostBack= false` in Upload control.

Comment: yes we can't do autopost back ., well @JAX can you tell me how can we post back please because my upload button is inside the details view and I did   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="upload" EventName="Click" />  but dint work

Comment: And I also did <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="upload"> but it didn't work as well.